# Python Selenium Google login bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, google-play

I'm trying to make a bot to automaticly use Google Play Gift Card on accounts. But I can't login. When I run my code Google says this browser is not secure. I tried using chromedriver and geckcodriver but didn't change anything. I tried using webbot instead of selenium but results are still the same. I even tried to open selenium webdriver and do everything manually but still gives the same error.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gb_70"]').click() #hit login button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys("username") #type username
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "İleri")]').click() #hit next(my language is different so İleri instead of Next)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“This browser or app may not be secure” error while attempting to login in to Gmail account using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515561/this-browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-error-while-attempting-to-login-in-to-gm)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** As of January 2021, this no longer works.

I know this is a late answer, but this is not impossible to do.

The following link comes from the Google OAuth playground.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email&access_type=offline&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

You can use that link (ie. `driver.get()`) to log into your Google account.

This bypasses the automation checks allows you to log into Google using Selenium. At least for now.

**UPDATE:** As of January 2021, this no longer works.

Comment: I used this code, am i doing it correct?

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email&access_type=offline&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow")

Comment: Why did I just get an upvote? This shouldn't have worked...

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you enter google's login page it detects that your browser has some functions enabled that normal browser does not have. It makes logging to the google services through selenium webdriver almost impossible.

Comment: I think this should be this should be rather a comment, than an answer.

Comment: @DemianWolf Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.

Comment: Is there any alternative rather than browser modifications?

Comment: @enes3626 yes. You have to find a way to make your browser to look like a `real one` and the user as not computer/bot but as a ,,real human".

Comment: @enes3626 can you upvote my comment and accept it? :)

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw, yes, you're right, they are mostly used for this. But they can also be used for ["adding relevant but minor or transient information to a post"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) as you, IMO, did here instead of giving the solution itself.

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw I upvoted it but can't accept it. I don't know how?

Comment: @enes3626 below the downvote button there is a,,tick" button. By clicking it you will accept my answer :)