# Python - Cannot login to any site with google account using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is what it shows me when I try to log in:[image]

What options.add_argument arguments should I use?
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

url = "url"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
options.add_argument("--window-size=1360,768")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“This browser or app may not be secure” error while attempting to login in to Gmail account using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515561/this-browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-error-while-attempting-to-login-in-to-gm)

Comment: Nothing worked :(

Comment: I can't see here you tried to insert your google account credentials.

Comment: There are several ways to log into the page I want to log into. Therefore, I want the user to choose the way of logging in and log in by himself after entering the login page.