# Python Selenium sign in

Tags: python, selenium, sign

So i want to compose a email to my another gmail account in selenium but they ask me to sign in to my google account i dont have any problem in signing in but can i automate that through a computer i tried to do it but i got a error always here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\\edge driver\\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(PATH)


driver.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox")
before = driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
before.send_keys("arkodeep.ray@gmail.com")
before.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
# link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Compose")
```

So whenever i run this code i get a error by google saying This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more Can anyone help me how to fix that i want to know how to fix that in selenium using a computer bot in msedge. Can someone help?

Here is the error i am getting [image: Image of the error]

Comment: or if you prefer headless mode then you won't see this issue

Comment: I need to try that out in Edge. I don't use edge. I think your chrome does not work properly right ?

Comment: Yes my pc shuts down i guess a reason may be my anti-virus is off

Comment: and i use windows 8.1

Comment: Windows should not be a problem I feel

Comment: what about firefox ?

Comment: OK but i dont know why i guess its some hardware failiure because twice in microsoft edge it happend but it usually does not happen in ms adge

Comment: I actually dont have firefox in my pc installed

Comment: It was my pc problem chrome was not the problem i just thought it was chrome work fine now i just have to repair my pc.

Comment: I figured out a solution to stop it from shutting down i can manage with it now but still i will try to repair it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“This browser or app may not be secure” error while attempting to login in to Gmail account using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515561/this-browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-error-while-attempting-to-login-in-to-gm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to resolve this issue:

1. Use Firefox instead of Chrome

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

2. Try to enable less secure apps to access your account.

You can find the option here:

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: Can i do it in microsoft edge