# Couldn't sign you in. This browser or app may not be secure. . Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and chrome driver to get into glassdoor's website for a project. Glassdoor requires me to login into my gmail account but when I try to login, it shows this error.

```
Couldn't sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in.
```

Is it because of Selenium or some setting in my browser? Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“This browser or app may not be secure” error while attempting to login in to Gmail account using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515561/this-browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-error-while-attempting-to-login-in-to-gm)