# Bard session cookies constantly changin in python

Tags: python, cookies, google-api, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to write a Python program using Bard, but everyday I have to change session cookies beacuse they are changing. Ho can I solve this? Here's the code:

```
import requests
from bardapi import Bard, SESSION_HEADERS


def split_long_string(input_string, max_length):
    divided_strings = []

    for i in range(0, len(input_string), max_length):
        divided_strings.append(input_string[i:i + max_length])

    return divided_strings

session = requests.Session()
token = "mytokenhere"
session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSID", mysessioncookiehere)
session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSIDCC", mysessioncookiehere)
session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSIDTS", mysessioncookiehere)
session.headers = SESSION_HEADERS

bard = Bard(token=token, session=session)


file_path = 'prova2.1.txt'
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
    transcription = file.read()


divided_strings = split_long_string(transcription, 7000)


combined_response = ""
for i, s in enumerate(divided_strings, start=1):
    answer = bard.get_answer("Summarize this transcription: " + s)
    combined_response += answer['content']


final_response = bard.get_answer("Join these summaries: {combined_response}")


print(final_response['content'])
```

I don't know how to use Bard api without using session cookies.

Comment: Why are you even using that package use the official one from google

Comment: Dude, hopefully your cookies cycled.. but word of advice, don't include your API keys (or cookies; same thing in this case) in your code.. and especially not in a public post. Bard is free for you, so you might not care.. but it's both bad practice and a security risk. Also, you might want to look into ENV files and removing API keys from your code base, just an FYI.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I found when looking was a PyPi project called bardToken, which is available here: https://pypi.org/project/bardToken/

Basically, it uses selenium to get the rolling API/Cookie automatically for you. I'm testing it right now, but it should be able to get the API headless (non-gui) using Selenium.

Edit: After running into a few issues, such as "This browser or app may not be secure” error when using Selenium (see: [“This browser or app may not be secure” error while attempting to login in to Gmail account using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515561/this-browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-error-while-attempting-to-login-in-to-gm)), this is the code that worked for me (but I could not get headless mode working):

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from bardapi import Bard
import seleniumGoogleLogin
import bardToken


if __name__ == '__main__':
    username = ''
    password = ''

    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.delete_all_cookies()

    # Google authentication
    if seleniumGoogleLogin.start(driver, username, password):
        token = bardToken.get(driver)  # Get bard token
        bard = Bard(token=token)

        question = "What is the current stock price of NVDA?"
        answer = bard.get_answer(question)['content']

        print(token)
        print(answer)
```

Update #2: This is my working code, that loads the API key from an ENV file, checks if the API key works and if not uses Selenium to get the latest key and caches/writes the results. For additional performance and to keep the context of the conversation, I create a session() as well.

```
import os
import requests
import bardToken
import seleniumGoogleLogin
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from datetime import datetime
from bardapi import Bard
from dotenv import load_dotenv


class BardApiHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        # Load environment variables from .env file
        load_dotenv()

        # Get environment variables
        self.BARD_API_KEY = os.getenv("BARD_API_KEY")
        self.USERNAME = os.getenv("USERNAME")
        self.PASSWORD = os.getenv("PASSWORD")

    def cache_credentials(self, api_key, username, password):
        # Cache credentials to .env file
        with open(".env", "w") as env_file:
            env_file.write(f"BARD_API_KEY={api_key}\n")
            env_file.write(f"USERNAME={username}\n")
            env_file.write(f"PASSWORD={password}\n")

    def get_bard_api(self):
        try:
            Bard(token=self.BARD_API_KEY)
        except:
            # Use selenium to get BARD_API_KEY if invalid/old & Cache.
            driver = uc.Chrome()
            driver.delete_all_cookies()

            if seleniumGoogleLogin.start(driver, self.USERNAME, self.PASSWORD):
                self.BARD_API_KEY = bardToken.get(driver)  # Get bard token
                # Cache key, username, and password
                self.cache_credentials(self.BARD_API_KEY, self.USERNAME, self.PASSWORD)
                # Close browser
                driver.quit()
        finally:
            # Setup browser session
            session = requests.Session()
            session.headers = {
                "Host": "bard.google.com",
                "X-Same-Domain": "1",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                              "Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
                "Origin": "https://bard.google.com",
                "Referer": "https://bard.google.com/",
            }
            session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSID", self.BARD_API_KEY)
            return Bard(token=self.BARD_API_KEY, session=session)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = datetime.now()

    bard_handler = BardApiHandler()
    bard = bard_handler.get_bard_api()

    question = "What is the current stock price of TSLA?"
    answer = bard.get_answer(question)['content']

    print(question)
    print(answer)

    print(f'The script executed in {datetime.now() - start}')
```

Output:

What is the current stock price of TSLA?

The current stock price of TSLA (Tesla, Inc.) is **$214.65** as of 2023-11-13 10:16 CST.

This is based on the data from CNBC, which is a reputable source for financial information.

The script executed in 0:00:10.405051